# How to send values to Arduino from python?

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to send angle values which gets from python script, and send this values to arduino for rotate servo motors. I used tutorials on youtube about mediapipe hand tracking. I am getting values of index finger's angle from 0 degrees to 180. But how am i going to send these values to servo motor and rotate it? Here is my code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import HandTrackingModule as htm
import math

import Utilities
from Utilities import connectToRobot

portNo = "COM5"
wCam, hCam = 640, 480

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3, wCam)
cap.set(4, hCam)
Utilities.connectToRobot(portNo)

detector = htm.handDetector(detectionCon=0.75)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()

    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList = detector.findPosition(img, draw=False)
    if len(lmList) != 0:
        #print(lmList[8], lmList[0])

        x1, y1 = lmList[8][1], lmList[8][2]
        x2, y2 = lmList[0][1], lmList[0][2]

        cv2.circle(img, (x1, y1), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.circle(img, (x2, y2), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 255), 3)

        length = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
        #print(length)

        # Index finger range 330 - 140
        # servo motor angle range 180 - 0

        angle = np.interp(length, [140, 300], [0, 180])
        print(int(angle))

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break
```

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks for advice.

These are the angles. You see maximum angle is 180 degrees and minimum is 0 degrees. I did not take 0 degrees because this is just `print(int(angle))` output for you to understand what i am trying to do.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLK3z.png) this is my hand btw. This photo show what code does. I drew purple line for calculate angle.

```
65
78
77
80
92
67
79
74
91
98
126
144
144
175
180
180
180
```